# C++ Show privileges Dialog on macOS 11

Tags: c++, qt, macos-big-sur

I'm writing an application on macOS 11 by using Qt5.15, how to show a privileges dialog?

simple code to me.
thanks！

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Show a "permission dialog" for *what*? What is your actual underlying problem? Why do you need to show this "permission dialog"? What have you tried yourself?